# LOAD DATA INFILE the entire file into a field

Tags: mysql, mariadb, load-data-infile, mariadb-10.5

I am storing the contents of text files in a table

```
CREATE TABLE Pages
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
Text mediumtext COMPRESSED,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=ARIA DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

I try to `INSERT` each file's contents directly via `LOAD DATA INFILE`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE table 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\0' LINES TERMINATED BY '' (Text) 
 SET ID=$id
```

The problem is that if I ideally use `TERMINATED BY ''`, it gives the error

> You can't use fixed rowlength with BLOBs; please use 'fields
> terminated by'

I used `'\0'` assuming the null character does not exist in the text file. Although it works, is there a more standard way to do so?

Comment: If you need to load the whole file and store its complete body into one column in one row then you must use not LOAD DATA statement but common INSERT/UPDATE statement with LOAD_FILE() function in it.

Comment: @Akina you are absolutely right, that's the correct way to do so.